# After two refusals of a Standard Visitor visa can I still apply again?

Tags: visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas

My friend was twice refused a Standard Visitor visa.

Can she reapply after she has corrected her mistakes?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Reapplication can be at *any* time but it would be highly inadvisable to do so soon after two refusals without expert advice to confirm that any corrections are likely to be suitable.

The chances are such advice already exists somewhere within [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstandard-visitor-visas%5D+closed%3A0+%5Bvisa-refusal%5D) but if no Q/A already covers your friend's situation you of your friend might care to post images (with  personal details suitably redacted) of the refusal letters for review here.

Comment: The refusal letter  images should, of course, have any personal data such as name blacked out.